# How do you achieve loose coupling / late binding with Azure integration

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How does one achieve loose coupling / late binding with Azure integration offerings such as Logic Apps?

When I produce a Logic App, it tightly couples itself to a trigger type, and if I chain onto Function Apps, it's also tightly bound to the instance of the app in an Azure tenancy.  I don't seem to be able to produce code that can be deployed into any subscription (as we have multiple environments and off shore teams), nor can I find a way of disconnecting things like the specific service bus queue it's working with and configure that are deployment.

This is all standard functionality we see with BizTalk which we're looking at alternatives to now because it seems Microsoft are pushing to the cloud.

Comment: On a very high level, you have to treat your deployment of Azure artifacts like the deployment of your BizTalk bindings - they would be tightly bound to your BTS instance where you create them unless you make them part of a build pipeline. There are a variety of tools that help you automating Azure infrastructure deployment.

Comment: ... and yes, of course MS is pushing Azure Integration tools but that doesn't guarantee the same level of maturity BizTalk has achieved. When faced with the decision, I went for migrating to BTS 2020 and only put some small, non-critical processes on LogicApps.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, it seems that separating the connector configuration from the logic app seems nigh-on-impossible, so it seems you're more looking at a build pipeline becoming a code generator, which seems like a massive step backwards.

Comment: And Microsoft have announced that Mainstream support for BizTalk 2020 has been extended to April 11, 2028, extended support still April 9, 2030.  So you have some time yet. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/biztalk-server-team-blog/biztalk-2020-mainstream-support/ba-p/3070573

Comment: And no, it is not impossible to do it with Logic Apps.  You need to look at ARM templates etc.